# Bootstrap collapse menu center items

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this bootsrap page with a collapsable search bar. I have a couple of things I want to do with it.

1. Make it wider and centered only when in the collapsable view
2. When the size gets down to sm the input changes to 100% width and the button moves to the next line. I want to keep the button on the same line and have the input + button = 100% width.

What would be the best way to do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap - Prebuilt Layout</title>

    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
      
      
      
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container" id="accordion">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
            <div class="navbar-header">
            
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSearch" data-pa aria-controls="navbarSearch" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
           </div>

           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent" data-parent="#accordion">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                 <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse search" id="navbarSearch" data-parent="#accordion">
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center">
       <h1 class="display-4">Bootstrap with Dreamweaver</h1>
       <p class="lead">Easily build your page using the Bootstrap components from the Insert panel.</p>
       <hr class="my-4">
       <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
       <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
       </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">Click outside the blue container to select this <strong>row</strong>. Columns are always contained within a row. <strong>Rows are indicated by a dashed grey line and rounded corners</strong>. </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <hr>
       <br>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <br><br>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                   <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <br>
             <br/>
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                   Featured
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                   <p class="card-text">Some text to build on the card's content.</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class=" col-md-4"> Click here to select this<strong> column.</strong> Always place your content within a column. Columns are indicated by a dashed blue line. </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>resize a column</strong> using the handle on the right. Drag it to increase or reduce the number of columns.</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>offset a column</strong> using the handle on the left. Drag it to increase or reduce the offset. </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h3>Adding <strong>Buttons</strong></h3>
                   <p>Quickly add buttons to your page by using the button component in the insert panel. </p>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Info Button</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Success Button</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-md-6">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h3>Adding <strong>Badges</strong></h3>
                   <p>Using the insert panel, add badge to your page by using the badge component.</p>
                   <span class="badge badge-info">Info Badge</span> <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger Badge</span>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <hr>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
             <h4>Footer </h4>
             <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="#" >My Website</a></p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For extra-small screens, the form-control is set to `display: block` and `width: 100%`. At small screens (≥576px), form-control switches to `display: inline-block` and `width: auto`. If you want your search box and button to always be on one line, then add the display and width settings for all screens.

To have the search form always in the center for medium and smaller screens, add `justify-content-center` to the form and use the left auto margin just on larger displays.

To have the search form and button take up 100% of the available width, add flex-grow-1 to the input (or you could give the input a class of w-75 and it will be larger, but not too big).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container" id="accordion">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
        <div class="navbar-header">


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSearch" data-pa aria-controls="navbarSearch" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent" data-parent="#accordion">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse search" id="navbarSearch" data-parent="#accordion">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-lg-auto justify-content-center">
                <input class="form-control mr-2 flex-grow-1" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Bootstrap with Dreamweaver</h1>
    <p class="lead">Easily build your page using the Bootstrap components from the Insert panel.</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    <p class="lead">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">Click outside the blue container to select this <strong>row</strong>. Columns are always contained within a row. <strong>Rows are indicated by a dashed grey line and rounded corners</strong>. </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br />
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Featured
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some text to build on the card's content.</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-4"> Click here to select this<strong> column.</strong> Always place your content within a column. Columns are indicated by a dashed blue line. </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>resize a column</strong> using the handle on the right. Drag it to increase or reduce the number of columns.</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>offset a column</strong> using the handle on the left. Drag it to increase or reduce the offset. </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Adding <strong>Buttons</strong></h3>
                    <p>Quickly add buttons to your page by using the button component in the insert panel. </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Info Button</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Success Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Adding <strong>Badges</strong></h3>
                    <p>Using the insert panel, add badge to your page by using the badge component.</p>
                    <span class="badge badge-info">Info Badge</span> <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger Badge</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
            <h4>Footer </h4>
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="#">My Website</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```